# Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable setup failed unspecified error [0x80240017]

Tags: mysql, visual-c++, visual-c++-2015

I'm trying to setup Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 in my pc because according to the instructions online I can't install MYSQL without it. However it's giving me an unspecified error.
Here's my log file.
Help would be apriciated.

> [1690:1340][2021-02-12T20:42:37]i001: Burn v3.7.3813.0, Windows v6.1
> (Build 7600: Service Pack 0), path: C:\Users\PC
> Admin\Downloads\vc_redist.x64.exe, cmdline: ''
> [1690:1340][2021-02-12T20:42:38]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value
> 'C:\Users\PCADMI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_amd64_20210212204238.log'
> [1690:1340][2021-02-12T20:42:38]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'C:\Users\PC
> Admin\Downloads\vc_redist.x64.exe'
> [1690:1340][2021-02-12T20:42:38]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder' to value 'C:\Users\PC
> Admin\Downloads'
> [1690:1340][2021-02-12T20:42:38]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleName' to value 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable
> (x64) - 14.0.24123'
> [1690:1340][2021-02-12T20:42:39]i100: Detect begin, 10 packages
> [1690:1340][2021-02-12T20:42:39]i000: File search: windows_uCRT_DetectKey, did not find path:
> C:\Windows\system32\ucrtbase.dll
> [1690:1340][2021-02-12T20:42:39]i000: File search: windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists, did not find path:
> C:\Windows\system32\ucrtbase.dll
> [1690:1340][2021-02-12T20:42:39]i000: Setting numeric variable 'windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists' to value 0
> [1690:1340][2021-02-12T20:42:39]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.3 AND NOT VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND
> windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
> [1690:1340][2021-02-12T20:42:39]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.3 AND VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND
> windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
> [1690:1340][2021-02-12T20:42:39]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.2 AND NOT VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND
> windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
> [1690:1340][2021-02-12T20:42:39]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.2 AND VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND
> windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
> [1690:1340][2021-02-12T20:42:39]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.1 AND NOT VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND
> windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
> [1690:1340][2021-02-12T20:42:39]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.1 AND VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND
> windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
> [1690:1340][2021-02-12T20:42:39]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.0 AND NOT VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND
> windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
> [1690:1340][2021-02-12T20:42:39]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.0 AND VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND
> windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
> [1690:1340][2021-02-12T20:42:39]i101: Detected package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
> [1690:1340][2021-02-12T20:42:39]i101: Detected package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
> [1690:1340][2021-02-12T20:42:39]i101: Detected package: Windows81_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
> [1690:1340][2021-02-12T20:42:39]i101: Detected package: Windows81_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
> [1690:1340][2021-02-12T20:42:39]i101: Detected package: Windows8_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
> [1690:1340][2021-02-12T20:42:39]i101: Detected package: Windows8_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
> [1690:1340][2021-02-12T20:42:39]i101: Detected package: Windows7_MSU_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
> [1690:1340][2021-02-12T20:42:39]i101: Detected package: Windows7_MSU_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
> [1690:1340][2021-02-12T20:42:39]i101: Detected package: WindowsVista_MSU_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
> [1690:1340][2021-02-12T20:42:39]i101: Detected package: WindowsVista_MSU_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
> [1690:1340][2021-02-12T20:42:39]i052: Condition 'VersionNT64 >= v6.0 OR (VersionNT64 = v5.2 AND ServicePackLevel >= 1)' evaluates to
> true.
> [1690:1340][2021-02-12T20:42:39]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
> [1690:1340][2021-02-12T20:42:42]i200: Plan begin, 10 packages, action: Install
> [1690:1340][2021-02-12T20:42:42]i052: Condition '(VersionNT64)' evaluates to true.
> [1690:1340][2021-02-12T20:42:42]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_vcRuntimeMinimum_x64' to value
> 'C:\Users\PCADMI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_amd64_20210212204238_000_vcRuntimeMinimum_x64_rollback.log'
> [1690:1340][2021-02-12T20:42:42]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_vcRuntimeMinimum_x64' to value
> 'C:\Users\PCADMI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_amd64_20210212204238_000_vcRuntimeMinimum_x64.log'
> [1690:1340][2021-02-12T20:42:42]i052: Condition '(VersionNT64)' evaluates to true.
> [1690:1340][2021-02-12T20:42:42]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_vcRuntimeAdditional_x64' to value
> 'C:\Users\PCADMI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_amd64_20210212204238_001_vcRuntimeAdditional_x64_rollback.log'
> [1690:1340][2021-02-12T20:42:42]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_vcRuntimeAdditional_x64' to value
> 'C:\Users\PCADMI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_amd64_20210212204238_001_vcRuntimeAdditional_x64.log'
> [1690:1340][2021-02-12T20:42:42]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.3 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
> [1690:1340][2021-02-12T20:42:42]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows81_x86
> [1690:1340][2021-02-12T20:42:42]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.3 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
> [1690:1340][2021-02-12T20:42:42]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows81_x64
> [1690:1340][2021-02-12T20:42:42]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.2 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
> [1690:1340][2021-02-12T20:42:42]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows8_x86
> [1690:1340][2021-02-12T20:42:42]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.2 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
> [1690:1340][2021-02-12T20:42:42]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows8_x64
> [1690:1340][2021-02-12T20:42:42]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.1 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
> [1690:1340][2021-02-12T20:42:42]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows7_MSU_x86
> [1690:1340][2021-02-12T20:42:42]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.1 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to true.
> [1690:1340][2021-02-12T20:42:42]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows7_MSU_x64
> [1690:1340][2021-02-12T20:42:42]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.0 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
> [1690:1340][2021-02-12T20:42:42]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers:
> WindowsVista_MSU_x86
> [1690:1340][2021-02-12T20:42:42]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.0 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
> [1690:1340][2021-02-12T20:42:42]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers:
> WindowsVista_MSU_x64
> [1690:1340][2021-02-12T20:42:42]i201: Planned package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba
> requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes,
> uncache: No, dependency: Register
> [1690:1340][2021-02-12T20:42:42]i201: Planned package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba
> requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes,
> uncache: No, dependency: Register
> [1690:1340][2021-02-12T20:42:42]i201: Planned package: Windows81_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested:
> Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No,
> dependency: None
> [1690:1340][2021-02-12T20:42:42]i201: Planned package: Windows81_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested:
> Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No,
> dependency: None
> [1690:1340][2021-02-12T20:42:42]i201: Planned package: Windows8_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested:
> Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No,
> dependency: None
> [1690:1340][2021-02-12T20:42:42]i201: Planned package: Windows8_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested:
> Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No,
> dependency: None
> [1690:1340][2021-02-12T20:42:42]i201: Planned package: Windows7_MSU_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba
> requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache:
> No, dependency: None
> [1690:1340][2021-02-12T20:42:42]i201: Planned package: Windows7_MSU_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba
> requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes,
> uncache: No, dependency: None
> [1690:1340][2021-02-12T20:42:42]i201: Planned package: WindowsVista_MSU_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba
> requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache:
> No, dependency: None
> [1690:1340][2021-02-12T20:42:42]i201: Planned package: WindowsVista_MSU_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba
> requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache:
> No, dependency: None
> [1690:1340][2021-02-12T20:42:42]i299: Plan complete, result: 0x0
> [1690:1340][2021-02-12T20:42:42]i300: Apply begin
> [14EC:0E60][2021-02-12T20:42:46]i360: Creating a system restore point.
> [14EC:0E60][2021-02-12T20:43:02]i361: Created a system restore point.
> [14EC:0E60][2021-02-12T20:43:02]i370: Session begin, registration key:
> SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall{2cbcedbb-f38c-48a3-a3e1-6c6fd821a7f4},
> options: 0x7, disable resume: No
> [14EC:0E60][2021-02-12T20:43:02]i000: Caching bundle from: 'C:\Users\PCADMI~1\AppData\Local\Temp{2cbcedbb-f38c-48a3-a3e1-6c6fd821a7f4}.be\VC_redist.x64.exe'
> to: 'C:\ProgramData\Package
> Cache{2cbcedbb-f38c-48a3-a3e1-6c6fd821a7f4}\VC_redist.x64.exe'
> [14EC:0E60][2021-02-12T20:43:02]i320: Registering bundle dependency provider: {2cbcedbb-f38c-48a3-a3e1-6c6fd821a7f4}, version:
> 14.0.24123.0
> [14EC:0E60][2021-02-12T20:43:02]i371: Updating session, registration key:
> SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall{2cbcedbb-f38c-48a3-a3e1-6c6fd821a7f4},
> resume: Active, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
> [14EC:0DE8][2021-02-12T20:43:05]i304: Verified existing payload: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package
> Cache.unverified\vcRuntimeMinimum_x64.
> [14EC:0DE8][2021-02-12T20:43:05]i305: Verified acquired payload: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package
> Cache.unverified\vcRuntimeMinimum_x64, moving to:
> C:\ProgramData\Package
> Cache{FDBE9DB4-7A91-3A28-B27E-705EF7CFAE57}v14.0.24123\packages\vcRuntimeMinimum_amd64\vc_runtimeMinimum_x64.msi.
> [14EC:0DE8][2021-02-12T20:43:06]i304: Verified existing payload: cab5046A8AB272BF37297BB7928664C9503 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package
> Cache.unverified\cab5046A8AB272BF37297BB7928664C9503.
> [14EC:0DE8][2021-02-12T20:43:06]i305: Verified acquired payload: cab5046A8AB272BF37297BB7928664C9503 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package
> Cache.unverified\cab5046A8AB272BF37297BB7928664C9503, moving to:
> C:\ProgramData\Package
> Cache{FDBE9DB4-7A91-3A28-B27E-705EF7CFAE57}v14.0.24123\packages\vcRuntimeMinimum_amd64\cab1.cab.
> [14EC:0DE8][2021-02-12T20:43:06]i304: Verified existing payload: vcRuntimeAdditional_x64 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package
> Cache.unverified\vcRuntimeAdditional_x64.
> [14EC:0DE8][2021-02-12T20:43:06]i305: Verified acquired payload: vcRuntimeAdditional_x64 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package
> Cache.unverified\vcRuntimeAdditional_x64, moving to:
> C:\ProgramData\Package
> Cache{21134089-9B59-34C8-BE11-929D26AD5207}v14.0.24123\packages\vcRuntimeAdditional_amd64\vc_runtimeAdditional_x64.msi.
> [14EC:0DE8][2021-02-12T20:43:06]i304: Verified existing payload: cab2C04DDC374BD96EB5C8EB8208F2C7C92 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package
> Cache.unverified\cab2C04DDC374BD96EB5C8EB8208F2C7C92.
> [14EC:0DE8][2021-02-12T20:43:06]i305: Verified acquired payload: cab2C04DDC374BD96EB5C8EB8208F2C7C92 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package
> Cache.unverified\cab2C04DDC374BD96EB5C8EB8208F2C7C92, moving to:
> C:\ProgramData\Package
> Cache{21134089-9B59-34C8-BE11-929D26AD5207}v14.0.24123\packages\vcRuntimeAdditional_amd64\cab1.cab.
> [14EC:0DE8][2021-02-12T20:43:06]i304: Verified existing payload: Windows7_MSU_x64 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package
> Cache.unverified\Windows7_MSU_x64.
> [14EC:0DE8][2021-02-12T20:43:06]i305: Verified acquired payload: Windows7_MSU_x64 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package
> Cache.unverified\Windows7_MSU_x64, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package
> Cache\54050A5F8AE7F0C56E553F0090146C17A1D2BF8D\packages\Patch\x64\Windows6.1-KB2999226-x64.msu.
> [14EC:0E60][2021-02-12T20:43:06]i301: Applying execute package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package
> Cache{FDBE9DB4-7A91-3A28-B27E-705EF7CFAE57}v14.0.24123\packages\vcRuntimeMinimum_amd64\vc_runtimeMinimum_x64.msi,
> arguments: ' MSIFASTINSTALL="7" NOVSUI="1"'
> [1690:1340][2021-02-12T20:43:15]i319: Applied execute package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64, result: 0x0, restart: None
> [14EC:0E60][2021-02-12T20:43:15]i325: Registering dependency: {2cbcedbb-f38c-48a3-a3e1-6c6fd821a7f4} on package provider:
> Microsoft.VS.VC_RuntimeMinimumVSU_amd64,v14, package:
> vcRuntimeMinimum_x64
> [14EC:0E60][2021-02-12T20:43:15]i301: Applying execute package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x64, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package
> Cache{21134089-9B59-34C8-BE11-929D26AD5207}v14.0.24123\packages\vcRuntimeAdditional_amd64\vc_runtimeAdditional_x64.msi,
> arguments: ' MSIFASTINSTALL="7" NOVSUI="1"'
> [1690:1340][2021-02-12T20:43:21]i319: Applied execute package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x64, result: 0x0, restart: None
> [14EC:0E60][2021-02-12T20:43:21]i325: Registering dependency: {2cbcedbb-f38c-48a3-a3e1-6c6fd821a7f4} on package provider:
> Microsoft.VS.VC_RuntimeAdditionalVSU_amd64,v14, package:
> vcRuntimeAdditional_x64
> [14EC:0E60][2021-02-12T20:43:21]i301: Applying execute package: Windows7_MSU_x64, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package
> Cache\54050A5F8AE7F0C56E553F0090146C17A1D2BF8D\packages\Patch\x64\Windows6.1-KB2999226-x64.msu,
> arguments: '"C:\Windows\SysNative\wusa.exe" "C:\ProgramData\Package
> Cache\54050A5F8AE7F0C56E553F0090146C17A1D2BF8D\packages\Patch\x64\Windows6.1-KB2999226-x64.msu"
> /quiet /norestart'
> [14EC:0E60][2021-02-12T20:43:30]e000: Error 0x80240017: Failed to execute MSU package.
> [1690:1340][2021-02-12T20:43:30]e000: Error 0x80240017: Failed to configure per-machine MSU package.
> [1690:1340][2021-02-12T20:43:30]i319: Applied execute package: Windows7_MSU_x64, result: 0x80240017, restart: None
> [1690:1340][2021-02-12T20:43:30]e000: Error 0x80240017: Failed to execute MSU package.
> [14EC:0E60][2021-02-12T20:43:30]i372: Session end, registration key:
> SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall{2cbcedbb-f38c-48a3-a3e1-6c6fd821a7f4},
> resume: ARP, restart: None, disable resume: No
> [14EC:0E60][2021-02-12T20:43:30]i371: Updating session, registration key:
> SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall{2cbcedbb-f38c-48a3-a3e1-6c6fd821a7f4},
> resume: ARP, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
> [1690:1340][2021-02-12T20:43:30]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x80240017, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No

Comment: Can you try running the command line for that patch from the logs separately, without the /quiet and see what happens? If you're lucky it might create its own log under your user AppData/Local/Temp.

Comment: FWIW err.exe says that 0x80240017 is either WU_E_NOT_APPLICABLE, Operation was not performed because there are no applicable updates, or ERROR_CRC i.e. your patch is corrupt. But it could equally mean something else, and possibly just the "Failed to configure per-machine MSU package" in your logs.

Comment: You can also try downloading a fresh copy of the KB2999226 patch from Microsoft and installing that separately.

Comment: I tried installing KB2999226  but it's saying "This update is not applicable to your computer".

Comment: OK, great, that's the 0x80240017 error then: WU_E_NOT_APPLICABLE. Is the VC++ runtime you're trying to install supported on your Windows version? If it is supposed to be, you're either going to have to extract the original VC++ installer and install all of the other component parts manually, and possibly also write some registry entry to convince the program that thinks you need to install the VC++ runtime that it's already installed successfully, or try and repack the VC++ installer so that it doesn't try and install KB2999226, e.g. with an MSI editor.

Comment: However I haven't tried to do that myself so I can't help. I suspect your problem is that this runtime isn't supported on your Windows version.

Comment: (Or possibly you're trying to install the 64-bit runtime on a 32-bit copy of Windows, but some of the earlier packages did install OK.)